# How to define GRPC service with empty request and Task<IActionResult> response

Tags: grpc, grpc-c#

GetAllTaxesList() method returns a generic return type of Task. But FetchTaxesList() returns the Taxs object. How to define response object in proto file.

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllTaxesList()
        { 
            try
            {
                var response = await sManager.FetchTaxesList().ConfigureAwait(false);
                return Ok(response);
            }           
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
            }
        }
```